# How to set focus on ion-button with Angular after component is initialized

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to set the focus on an ion-button after the component is initialized. I manage to focus on an input field after the component is initialized, but not on an ion button.

Angular Component:

This method is called inside the ngOninit() lifecycle method.

```
  private _setFocusDefault(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const element = document.getElementById("buttonback");

      if (element) {
        if (element !== document.activeElement) {
          const activeEl: any = document.activeElement;
          activeEl.blur();
          element.focus();
        } else {
          element.focus();
        }
      }
    }, 2000);
  }
```

View (button that needs the focus):

```
 <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button id="buttonback" expand="block" class="bodybutton backbutton" (click)="cancel()">
          <ion-icon id="iconButtonBack" class="iconButtonBack" name="arrow-back" attr.aria-label="{{ constants.BACK_TO_PREV_SCREEN }}"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
 </ion-buttons>
```

Anyone any idea why I can't set the focus on the ion-button? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix by using tabindex="0" on the ion-button element.

```
 <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button tabindex="0" id="buttonback" expand="block" class="bodybutton backbutton" (click)="cancel()">
          <ion-icon id="iconButtonBack" class="iconButtonBack" name="arrow-back" attr.aria-label="{{ constants.BACK_TO_PREV_SCREEN }}"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
 </ion-buttons>
```

Source: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/21439